# Generate javascript and html blocks on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

In my website, I'm currently using 3 csv files, that are rendered by highcharts with the following javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.get('export_xxxx.csv', function(csv) {
      $('#xxx').highcharts({
         data: {
            csv: csv
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Twitter (@xxxxx)'
         },
         yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
               text: 'Users'
            }
         },
         series: [{
            visible: true
         }, {
            visible: false
         }],
         plotOptions: {
            line: {
               dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true
              }
            } 
         },
      });
   });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $.get('export_xxxxyy.csv', function(csv) {
      $('#xxx').highcharts({
         data: {
            csv: csv
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Twitter (@xxxx)'
         },
         yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
               text: 'Users'
            }
         },
         series: [{
            visible: true
         }, {
            visible: false
         }],
         plotOptions: {
            line: {
               dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true
               }
            }
         },
      });
   });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $.get('export_xxx_.csv', function(csv) {
      $('#xxx').highcharts({
         data: {
            csv: csv
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Twitter (@xxx)'
         },
         yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
               text: 'Users'
            }
         },
         series: [{
            visible: true
         }, {
            visible: false
         }],
         plotOptions: {
            line: {
               dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true
               }
            }
         },
      });
   });
});
```

and 3 html lines (It's like a dashboard).

```html
<div id="xxx" style="width: 49%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;float:left;"></div>
```

My wish is to craft an HTML page with javascript of highcharts, to handle as many as csv there is in the DocumentRoot of my website.

For example, if I put 10 csv files, the generic HTML file will display 10 different charts on the same page, without editing manually the HTML page and add javascript too. Generated on the fly, in function of how many csv file there is.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Repetitive code you can wrap your common code into `function` and call when you need to render chart with data.

`renderCharts` function accept csv data and id value.

```
function renderCharts(data,key){
 $('#' + key).highcharts({
               data: {
                  csv: data
               },
               title: {
                  text: 'Twitter (@xxx)'
               },
               yAxis: {
                  allowDecimals: false,
                  title: {
                     text: 'Users'
                  }
               },
               series: [{
                  visible: true
               }, {
                  visible: false
               }],
               plotOptions: {
                  line: {
                     dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
      }
      }
}})
};


$(document).ready(function() {
   var ids = ['export_xxx_.csv','export_xxxxyy.csv','export_xxxxyyddd.csv'];
   var promises = [];
  ids.forEach(function(id){
      promises.push($.get(id));
  });

  $.when(promises).then(function(values){
    values.forEach(function(value){
      renderCharts(value,'xxx');
   })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your webserver gives a JSON response for list of files, say like this,

`[ '/data1.csv', /date2.csv', ... ]`

You can use something like this

```
$.get('/data', function(listOfFiles) {
  for (var i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    $('body').append('<div id="chart' + i + '" style="width: 49%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;float:left;"></div>');
    $.get(listOfFiles[i], function(csv) {
      $('#chart' + i).highcharts({
        .....
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Ideally though, you should have a API retrieving data from a 
 database instead of using files.